# Called Activity can not accept events

Tags: rhapsody

For my Rhapsody model I want to model a loop of actions in activitity `Act2`, which can be interrupted by an event. As activity `Act2` is used in multiple places, I use the activity as a Call Behavior in activity `Act1`.

But I get the following error:

> Called Activity can not accept events
>
> AcceptEventAction : accepteventaction_19 in Pkg1::UseCases::UC1::Act2
>
> CallBehavior : Act2 in Pkg1::UseCases::UC1::Act1

I'm unsure what I'm missing in my model?

I use Rhapsody 8.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a limitation of my used version 8.3.1

[Release notes of 8.4.0](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10874170#ABOUT) state:

> Activity diagrams: Call Behavior elements that reference activity diagrams that contain Accept Event Actions
>
> Animation now supports activity diagrams with Call Behavior elements that reference activity diagrams containing Accept Event Actions (for C++ only)

**EDIT:**

I can confirm this problem was fixed in Rhapsody version 8.4.0